# What does \renewcommand*{\rmdefault}{fxlj} exactly do?

Tags: fonts, formatting, bold, libertine, roman

I'm writing a document with multiple hundred of pages and noticed some *glitches* with the selected font I use. I'm using a template provided by the institute I'm working at. The font I have chosen is `libertine`.

This is - what I could break down - a minimal *working* example of Libertine in action:

```
\documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
   \noindent This text is \textbf{bold}.
   \section{Minimal working example}
   This text \textit{isn't}.
\end{document}
```

Now, however, does the class definition file of my template include another statement that I can not comprehend, and - breaks everything font related:

```
  \renewcommand*{\rmdefault}{fxlj}
```

This causes the default font to be reset to *Roman*, which I do not want. And sometimes the font is not default Roman, but Libertine. However, bold and italic Libertine is not working anymore.

This is the most basic minimal *not working* example I could come up with:

```
\documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{libertine}
  \renewcommand*{\rmdefault}{fxlj}
\begin{document}
   \noindent This text is \textbf{bold}.
   \section{Minimal not working example}
   This text \textit{isn't}.
\end{document}
```

Now, I want to understand what the `\renewcommand*{\rmdefault}{fxlj}` command exactly does, and - important - what the intention is. Simply removing it seems to fix my issue, but I can't do this unless I *understand* the implications.

Comment: It defines the font family that should be used, whenever `\rmfamily` or `\textrm` is used. But if it is in the class file and not delayed with `\AtBeginDocument` or similar, it should not matter, because `libertine` also redefines `\rmdefault`.

Comment: BTW: AFAIR `fxlj` was the family name of one of the Libertine Type-1 fonts, several years ago, now only avaliable as obsolete package [`libertine-legacy`](http://ctan.org/pkg/libertine-legacy). AFAIK support of that old Libertine version ended 2009 or 2010.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a consequence of using low level commands in documents instead of packages.

When you compile your document, you get the warnings

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/fxlj/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 4.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/fxlj/b/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/fxlj/m/n' instead on input line 5.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/fxlj/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/fxlj/m/n' instead on input line 7.
```

The first warning tells you that the family `fxlj` corresponds to no `.fd` file for the OT1 encoding, so a default substitution is made, with the standard `cmr` family. The other two might be misleading if one doesn't take into consideration the fact that LaTeX has already decided that `fxlj` becomes `cmr`.

The naming scheme suggests that `fxlj` should point to Linux Libertine with oldstyle digits (the trailing `j`), but the family name has changed over time. Nowadays the font family for Linux Libertine is called

```
LinuxLibertineT-<suffix>
```

The suffix can be

```
TLF
TOsF
LF
OsF
```

where `LF` stands for “lining figures” and `OsF` for “oldstyle figures”; the `T` means “tabular figures”, if absent it means that proportional figures are used.

Thus with Linux Libertine it's a bad idea to set directly the family name: better use the higher level calls:

```
\usepackage[
  %tabular,
  %proportional,
  %lining,
  %oldstyle,
]{libertine}
```

Uncomment the keys you need.

Comment: This is a really nice answer that highlights a type of problem that is probably more common than we would like to see, while pointing us in the proper direction of using higher-level commands, where possible.

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually using the higher level commands already, just removed them to make the mwe as _minimal_ as possible. Now I'm confident, the leftovers of the very old template can simply be removed. After some testing, the results are fine.